# Wait for child process to terminate in R

Tags: r

I have multiple r script which I source on one script. I want to run each script at a time such that the second script should wait until the first script is over.
Is their a function like wait() which is use in python subprocess package?
is their similar package in R?

Comment: Are you saying you have one input file with multiple tasks?

Comment: You need to include a minimal, reproducible example; your question is unclear from the description alone.

Comment: source(test1.R) source(test2.R) after running first script second script should run

Comment: basically I am calling these two scripts with in a single script in crone job and it is running only first script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following should work in the way you describe -- `file_2.R` will not run until the first `source()` is complete.

```
source('file_1.R')
source('file_2.R')
```

Note that, by default, elements in the called script's environment will be available in the global environment (and therefore to anything you source thereafter. You can disable this behavior with the argument `local=TRUE`).

Comment: basically I am calling these two scripts with in a single script in crone job and it is running only first script.